# How to get all Labels to edit in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have 5 label that I created by drag & drop on the form. Is there an array of these labels (that's already created) that I can use?

If I wanted to enter text into all these label for example, would I able to do it through creating a loop and assign each element of labels array a particular text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". There is no array already created for just the 5 labels you created using drag and drop.

You can iterate through **all** the children of a form (and recursively for controls placed on container controls on your form), but you would get back all the controls on the form and not just the 5 labels.

You could use a specific naming for these labels - like `label_1`, `label_2`, `label_3`, `label_4`, `label_5` and filter based on `.Name.Starts("label_")` to allow you to update these labels specifically.

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no array of labels But just a collection of controls.
you can choose the Labels from the form's control collection and enter text into all these labels.
like this method :

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        c.Text = "Your String";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite `new Label().GetType()` as `typeof(Label)`? Or just `c is Label`?

Comment: in .net 4.0 "c" (which is a System.Web.Ui.Control) does not have a method or property called "text".